# Nginx Reverse Proxy with Multiple Backend Domains

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a 2 servers :-

Server 1 : NGINX Reverse Proxy.

Server 2 : NGINX with 5-6 websites ( different domains )

So basically, all users will come to Server 1 which will proxy_pass the traffic to Server 2 and get the response back. Server 1 will also do Caching, WAF etc.

Here is my configuration for Server 1 :-

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location ~* {
     proxy_pass http://mysite:80;
}
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server.com www.server.com;

  location ~* {
     proxy_pass http://mysite:80;
}
}
```

In my Server 2, in virtual.conf of NGINX, i have the following config :

```
index index.php index.html;
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/websites/example/;
        include location-php;
    }
}

    server {
        listen   80;
        server_name  server.com www.server.com;

        location / {
            root   /var/www/websites/server/;
            include location-php;
        }
    }
```

However whenever i go to http://example.com or http://server.com ( directed via Sever 1 acting as Reverse Proxy ), it shows the Server 2's Default NGINX Page.  I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Also is this type of setup a proper way of doing things ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your **host** problem.
Due to your upstream name is **mysite**, so the host name in upstream request is **mysqsite** too.
So the host isn't matched by the backend servers.

You can solve the problem like this by adding the directive before **proxy_pass**:
`proxy_set_header Host server.com`

Comment: Thanks alot ZYWG. It seems to be working now. So for this, I had to add /etc/host entry for server.com and example.com pointing to the backend server IP. So is this the correct way to do it ? I have 5-6 domains and for each one of them, I had to add IP in the /etc/hosts.

Comment: You don't need add anything to /etc/hosts.  The server_name in nginx.conf is just a string to match the host in request.  You just proxy_set_header Host server.name; proxy_pass http:// 127.0.0.1; Then nginx will parse the host.

Comment: Aah. That seems better way. Thanks alot for your help :) Cheers